# Dockerfile pass RUN command result as target for COPY

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run a command: `RUN find / -type d -name 'somefolder'` and pass the result as a variable to the `COPY` command:

```
RUN find / -type d -name 'somefolder' <---- put into variable
COPY text.txt variable  <---------- use it
```

`ARG` and `ENV` don't seem like what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to pass as a variable?

Comment: `ARG` is available for build, `ENV` is available in the container.

Comment: I want to pass the `RUN` result as a target for the `COPY` command

Comment: I do not understand. What do you want to copy?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Just `COPY test.txt /some_file.txt` and `RUN mv /some_file.txt /somefolder`? Or if you really have to `RUN find / -type d -name 'somefolder' -exec mv /some_file.txt {} \;` but I wonder why do you use `find` at all...

Comment: I need to find the folder path before I copy files to that folder. So I want to use `RUN find` to get the path I'm gonna copy into

Comment: Generally you can just pick a fixed path inside the image.  Since an image typically only contains one version of one application you don’t usually need to do tricky things with dynamic paths.

Comment: Do that inside the `RUN` parameter

Comment: Nicet try, but I've been told that you can't do this because `COPY` doesn't see the variable created as it works on the docker level, not container level (where the variable is defined).